# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I registered two httpclient in startup.I want to get httpclient according to different names in other services

```
public class WechatLogicService : IWechatLogicService{
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider;
    private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> options;
    private readonly ILogger<WechatLogicService> logger;
    private IWeChatRefundHttpClinet httpClient;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;
    public WechatLogicService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor,
            ILogger<WechatLogicService> logger,
              IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
                IOptions<AppSettings> options)
        {
            this.accessor = accessor;
            this.options = options;
            this.logger = logger;
            provider = serviceProvider;
        }
     public void Refund(){
           settings = options.Value.WeChatSettings.Settings.First(p => p.MchId 
                   == refundDto.Account);
           httpClient = provider.GetServices<IWeChatRefundHttpClinet> 
                   ().First(p => p.GetType().Name.Contains(settings.Scoped));
     }
 }
```

Startup:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IEnterpriseHttpClient, EnterpriseAppHttpClient>(option =>
{
    option.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("EnterpriseAppSettings")["Domain"].ToString());
});
services.AddHttpClient<IEnterpriseHttpClient, EnterpriseNormalHttpClient>(option =>
{
    option.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("EnterpriseNormalSettings")["Domain"].ToString());
});
services.AddScoped<IWechatLogicService, WechatLogicService>();
```

It throws an exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.

I am confused about what went wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow but should you not be taking a dependency on `IEnterpriseHttpClient` rather than `IServiceProvider`? Also, did you mean to register both clients against the `IEnterpriseHttpClient` interface?

Comment: If you write this: `provider.GetServices<IWeChatRefundHttpClinet>().First(p => p.GetType().Name.Contains(settings.Scoped));` you're working against the grain of the dependency injection system. The right service should be set up from the beginning, and if you need to make a distinction between the two, have two objects implementing different interfaces, and ask for the right interface.

Comment: As for the question - it looks as if the service provider is scoped, and is disposed [with each request/scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes) and the Refund method is called afterwards.

Comment: @GregStanley yeah,i register to different clients against the IEnterpriseHttpClient interface..

Comment: It's recommended to avoid depending directly on `IServiceProvider`. That's called the service locator antipattern. If you depend on it then classes can request anything from it, so there's no way to tell what classes actually depend on.